# Capture `active (running)` from the output of a `systemctl` command

Tags: shell-script

Currently an active service(`telegraf`) is running on a machine. Want to automate few steps in which the initial is to check the service is running from a `shell script`.

I am running `systemctl status telegraf` command to check the status of the service manually. and the output is,

```
telegraf.service - The plugin-driven server agent for reporting metrics into InfluxDB
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/telegraf.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-05-19 12:26:17 UTC; 3 weeks 5 days ago
     Docs: https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf
 Main PID: 1297 (telegraf)
    Tasks: 9 (limit: 49778)
   Memory: 106.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/telegraf.service
           └─1297 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
```

I want to capture the value ***active (running)*** in my script, how to do it in Shell script?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could parse the output of the `systemctl status` command.

But the easier way to get information on whether a service is running is by using the `is-active` sub command of `systemctl`. For example:

```
user@host:~$ systemctl is-active postfix
active
```

If the service is not active the returned string is `inactive`.

So in your script you can either check the string that is returned (active or inactive) or you can check the return code of the above mentioned command.
If the service is active the command returns with 0 otherwise it'll retrun with non-zero return code.

Greetings :)